# When Bnei Yisroel travelled in the midbar, what happened on Shabbos?

Tags: shabbat, dor-hamidbar, lechem-hapanim

When Bnei Yisroel travelled in the midbar, what happened on Shabbos? Did they encamp on erev Shabbos and journey after  Shabbos or did they continue journeying despite the laws of Shabbos?

If they continued journeying on Shabbos what happened to the lechem haponim? It would seem that they would be on the shulchan for more than a week.

Comment: Are you talking about before Marah/Alush (depending on your Rishon as to when they became obligated in Hilchos Shabbos), or after?

Comment: After they became obligated in Hilchos Shabbos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Tosafos to Menachos 95a](https://www.sefaria.org/Tosafot_on_Menachot.95a.16?lang=he) says that of course they didn't travel on Shabbos:

> ועל כרחיך בשבת לא היו נוסעין דאפילו לא היו תחומין מדאורייתא לא היו יכולין ליסע משום איסור הוצאה ואיסור מחמר
>
> You have to say that they didn't travel on Shabbos. Even if techumin are not binding mideoraisa, they wouldn't have been able to travel because of the prohibitions on carrying and on driving animals.

Anyway, though, it wouldn't matter if the lechem haponim somehow wasn't taken off the shulchan on Shabbos:

> שאפילו היא על השולחן ימים רבים אין בכך כלום
>
> Even if the bread remains on the shulchan for many days, there's no issue with that. ([Menachos 100a](https://www.sefaria.org/Menachot.100a))